# CSS, Tooltip: Having a auto-resize background according to tooltip text

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

Using this [codepen](https://codepen.io/shimdim/pen/NjyNNb), I want to show the tooltip that can auto-resize. What I mean is, if there is a long text to be displayed as the tooltip message, can the tooltip box be resize to adjust the message in multiple lines? I know that ideally tooltip is supposed to be a few words at best, but still, I'm just curious to explore it.

**Current:**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

Should I change the `display`attribute? I tried changing to `flex, inline, inline-flex, etc`. but none worked. Even tried with `width: auto` but I think that will require some more logic.

Comment: `[data-title]:hover::before { white-space: inherit; }`

Comment: @GrafiCode This causes the little arrow to overlap the tooltip.

Comment: can you provide the code.Try using bootstrap tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
[data-title] {
  outline: red dotted 1px; /*optional styling*/
  font-size: 30px; /*optional styling*/
  
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
}

[data-title]:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  word-break: break-word;
  max-width: 150px;
}
[data-title]:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 8px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Styling html title tooltip</h1>
<span data-title="Here is some extra long text that should break the line">Hover me</span>
```

I changed `bottom: -26px;` to `top: calc(100% + 10px);`.
I removed `white-space: inherit;`.
I added `word-break: break-word;`.
I added `max-width: 150px;`.

Currently the width of the tooltip is limited by either `max-width` or the width of the span. You could add `min-width` but that could leave a lot of blank space if the text isn't long enough.

These changes should position the tooltip and the little arrow pointer thingy correctly so the neither overlap.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Can you explain me the purpose of `[data-title]:hover::after` here? Removing it still runs the code fine

Comment: The `::after` piece is what creates the little arrow.

Comment: I tried using the `[data-title]` within an `<input>` tag in a` table. The tooltip doesn't appear, can you please help me finding out the reason for it?
      
`<table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input data-title="Here is some text for example. It is a very very very very long text"></input>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: @VasuMistry Unfortunately `::before` and `::after` does not work on input elements. You can always wrap the input with a span that has the `data-title` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Change from no wrap to wrap

```
[data-title]:hover::before {white-space: wrap; }
```

Comment: This causes the little arrow to overlap the tooltip.